# class has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

I have two classes:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void somefunction() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B();
    ~B();
    void somefunction();
};

B::B() {}

void B::somefunction() {
    //  some code
}
```

But with g++ I get errors:

```
class A has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor
class B has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor
```

I don't have any idea what this error is... Somewhere on blogs I read that it's a compiler warning. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This happens because your base class `A` does not have a virtual destructor. For instance, if you had this code:

```
int main()
{
    A* a = new B;
    delete a;
}
```

Then the `delete a` call would not be able to call `B`'s destructor because `A`'s isn't virtual. (It would leak all of `B`'s resources.) You can [read more about virtual destructors here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Virtual_destructors).

Add a virtual destructor to your base class and you should be fine.

```
class A
{
public:  
    virtual void somefunction() = 0;
    virtual ~A() = default;
}
```

Comment: @SPB It means it couldn't find an implementation of your destructor. Write a trivial one if you have nothing to actually destroy. `A::~A() { }` should do it.

Answer (score 7):

Give class A:

```
virtual ~A() { }
```

That way, derived classes such as B will still have their custom destructor called if you `delete` them via an `A*`.

Answer (score 4):

As thumb rule(IMHO) or in Short the **destructor** in the base class has to be either public and virtual or protected non virtual to  prevent the memory leaks.by doing so the **destructors** of the derived class get called and this prevents the **memory leakage** whenever the Base **pointer/reference** holding derived **address/reference** is deleted.

Comment: While I agree with this. Unfortunately GCC's warnings don't. I.e. it will still emit this warning when the destructor in the base class is declared `protected`.

Answer (score 2):

If a class has virtual functions then its destructor should be virtual as well. Yours has an accessible destructor but it is not virtual.